# I'm trying to retrieve a custom content type onto the user profile page

Tags: blocks, users, views, nodes

I'm using D7.
I have a custom content type that I need to relate to the user. The user will set up and maintain this page themselves.
i.e. Each user has one page of content for this content type.

When a user profile is viewed though I need to show the relevant page that relates to the the user.

What's the best way of doing this in D7?
I'm guessing it's something to do with creating a block view and then using contextual filters. I've managed to get a block view that does this within the preview but I can't get any further than that in terms of linking it to a user profile.

There is the possibility of linking the user name to the content title. In fact if the two were intrinsically linked it would be better. Ideally I would have used the profile 2 module but I'm using location ( doesn't work with users in D7 ) and FiveStar ( doesn't work with users in D7 ).

Any suggestions on where to start looking to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module. It replaces the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module from Drupal 6 and the profile module that is build into Drupal Core.

Comment: Hi Oswald, Thanks for the answer. I have got Profile 2 installed but a couple of the features I'm looking to implement - 5 star rating of this page and geolocation proximity search don't work with user profiles from what I've read. Unless somebody knows differently.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a node reference on the profile and populate it with an empty node, when the profile is created. Then it's just a matter of theming when it comes to displaying that node on the profile page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've actually solved this. I'll post how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this. Here's how I did it.

In Advanced settings:

First, I created a relationship in the view to link the content to the user profile. This was achieved by selecting content:author.

Next I created a contextual filter using this relationship on user:id.

On Page Settings:

I then set the path up to be user/%/content, this allows the user page to bring up the relevant content that the user has posted.

Finally, I created a menu tab on the user menu.

Job done!

Next I need to find a way to ensure that each user can only create one page of the relevant content. Any suggestions?

Comment: if this is your chosen solution, please mark the answer as accepted for future visitors.